# Get classes from JSON in Crystal

Tags: json, serialization, crystal-lang

I have some JSON file like this:

```
{
    "2": {
        "_id": 2,
        "_date": "Mon Apr 05 2021",
        "_timestamp": 1617654662313,
        "description": "Some text",
        "isStarred": true,
        "boards": [
            "@3.0",
            "@Some-day"
        ],
        "_isTask": false,
        "isComplete": false,
        "inProgress": false,
        "priority": 1
    },
    "7": {
        "_id": 7,
        "_date": "Mon Apr 05 2021",
        "_timestamp": 1617658197721,
        "description": "Some text too",
        "isStarred": false,
        "boards": [
            "@Some-day"
        ],
        "_isTask": false
    }
```

}

and I want to parse it in my class `Entry`:

```
  require "json"

  enum Priority
      Low # 1
      Medium # 2
      High # 3
  end

  class Entry
      include JSON::Serializable
      property _id : UInt32
      property _date : Time
      property _timestamp : UInt64
      property description : String
      property isStarred : Bool
      property boards : Array(String)
      property _isTask : Bool
      property isComplete : Bool
      property inProgress : Bool
      property priority : Priority
  end
```

When I try to parse using `Hash(String, Entry).from_json` it does not work: `Expected BeginObject but was String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error, there's no `from_string` method in the standard library, so the fault might be within whatever that is.

However using `from_json`  still requires some adjustments to your example:

1. The date format in `_date`  is non-standard and requires an explicit `Time::Format` passed as a field converter using the `@[JSON::Field]` annotation's `converter` attribute.
2. Similarly enums serialize to their name value as a string by default and require `Enum::ValueConverter` to be set to serialize to their numerical value instead.
3. Going by your example JSON some of the properties are optional and need to be marked as nilable.

https://carc.in/#/r/e2e7

The `@[JSON::Field]` annotation is also handy to set different external names while using more conventional names on the Crystal side of things.

Comment: You have to put `require "json"`. I edited the question

Comment: Can you produce a self contained example on carc.in that reproduces your error message? I consider `json` as part of the standard library and it doesn't define any `from_string` method either.

Comment: Sorry. It's `from_json`